# how to use this recursive code in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, recursion, recursive-query, orgchart

db_connection.php

```
<?php
define('_HOST_NAME', 'localhost');
define('_DATABASE_USER_NAME', 'root');
define('_DATABASE_PASSWORD', '');
define('_DATABASE_NAME', 'test_database');

 $dbConnection = new mysqli(_HOST_NAME, _DATABASE_USER_NAME, _DATABASE_PASSWORD, _DATABASE_NAME);
 if ($dbConnection->connect_error) {
      trigger_error('Connection Failed: '  . $dbConnection->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
 }
 $_GLOBAL['dbConnection'] = $dbConnection; 
?>
```

function.php

```
<?php 
function categoryParentChildTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $category_tree_array = '') {
global $dbConnection;
$parent = $dbConnection->real_escape_string($parent);
if (!is_array($category_tree_array))
    $category_tree_array = array();

$sqlCategory = "SELECT id,name,parent_id FROM tbl_categories WHERE parent_id = $parent ORDER BY id ASC";
$resCategory=$dbConnection->query($sqlCategory);

if ($resCategory->num_rows > 0) {
    while($rowCategories = $resCategory->fetch_assoc()) {
        $category_tree_array[] = array("id" => $rowCategories['id'], "name" => $spacing . $rowCategories['name']);
        $category_tree_array = categoryParentChildTree($rowCategories['id'], '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$spacing . '-&nbsp;', $category_tree_array);
    }
}
return $category_tree_array;
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'db_connection.php';
require_once 'functions.php';

$categoryList = categoryParentChildTree(); 
foreach($categoryList as $key => $value){
    echo $value['name'].'<br>';
}
?>
```

can anyone help me to translating this so i can use on codeigniter? recursive function
sorry im new on codeigniter
please help

Comment: setup your database first from `application/config/database.php`.then i can help you?

Comment: you are not following `CI` functionality. Use `Active records` for query. As said by @HikmatSijapati setup you Db in database.php. [ https://www.codeigniter.com/docs ]

Comment: @HikmatSijapati  that code is work for basic php without frame work exactly. 
im need help how to run it with CI framework. couse if i just copy paste that on my controller , model, and view. that code cant run
can you help me how to run it in CI frame work?
which one in controller/model/view
sorry for my bad english btw
please help

Comment: @NishantNair can you help me ?  that code cant run. can you help me how to run it in CI frame work? couse that code for basic php without frame work. which one in controller/model/view 
sorry for my bad english btw

Comment: You can set you database connection as shown here. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

CodeIgniter follows MVC architecture 
Please have a look at the basics of CodeIgniter framework here https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html.